# odbc::dbWriteTable error - Invalid column name 'row_names'

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am trying to append records from a dataframe in R to an established SQL data table using the odbc::dbWriteTable() function. This is a function I use for many workflows to append records to various database tables.

Specifically:
*odbc::dbWriteTable(connection, DBI::SQL(glue("{database}.{schema}.{table}")), value = dataframe, append = TRUE)*

The dataframe and the target SQL table share the same column names and variable types.

However, when I attempt to run the function and append the data records, I receive the following error:

*Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) :
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:####: ######: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'row_names'. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.*

The dataframe contains no row names. Why is the column name "row_names" being generated, and is there a way to ensure this column name is not generated? Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar issues, the answer was very simple. I just needed to add

```
row.names=FALSE
```

to the import function:

```
odbc::dbWriteTable(connection, DBI::SQL(glue("{database}.{schema}.{table}")), value = dataframe, append = TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```